# How to check if user has installed/updated Google Play services?

Tags: android

My Android app requires Google Play services to display Google Maps. I've included a function call that checks for the availability of Google Play services and proceed if it exists. If it doesn't exist or has an outdated version, an error dialog is shown that redirects user to Play Store. I wanted to ask, how can I check if a user has actually installed (or updated) Google Play services when they land back to my app? I'm using `Fragment` and checking for the availability of Google Play services in `onResume()`.

The function is as follow:

```
private boolean isPlayServicesConfigured() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        return true;
    else {
        Log.d("STATUS", "Error connecting with Google Play services. Code: " + String.valueOf(status));
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), status);
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Moreover, even if I get the status of Google Play Services back in my app, how do I reload the fragment? Can I call `onCreateView()` programatically?

Comment: What error you get in above code? that piece of code should work from your app

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I want to devise a way to know whether a user has installed/updated Google Play services as they're redirected to Play Store to do so.